# Backpack for Laravel - Column with formatted text

Tags: text, formatted

I am wondering how to add a column with formatted text. I need to add 
 tag to make multi line column in show Operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

$this->crud->addColumn(['name' => 'myName', 'label' => 'myLabel', 'type' => 'text', 'escaped' => false]);

So add index 'escaped' with value false.